# About Transaction knowledge

Tags: mysql, postgresql, sql-server-2012, rdbms

Am teaching myself SQL. And I never worked in any enterprise company but I have watched and learned some tutorials about web development and I see crud applications used to inject data into a database using Data Manipulate Language(DML) such as insert, update, delete. And Am asking if should they use TCL. What I mean is, if you are working with an enterprise client am I supposed to perform this query as a Transaction? Or should I perform that operation using DML command direct, what if an error occurred and what about ACID property am I getting any advantage of not use TCL commands? Please help me understand this or point me in any direction so I can learn. Disclaimer: I apologize for my English

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Some (can) have autocommit by default while others require explicit transaction control.

Comment: Hi @Colin'tHart , I would like to know more about the general concept. In enterprise settings, should every insertion of data be considered a transaction? For example when The auto-configuration of any database system does not matter or is not auto-configured

Comment: The scope of this question is too wide, the answer would require at least a long essay! You should obtain a text and go through it and come back to us with more detailed questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I mean is, if you are working with an enterprise client am I supposed to perform this query as a Transaction?

If the use case requires that the data is transactionally consistent after being manipulated then you should use a transaction, but that's your choice. In other words, if you're making multiple changes to the data (DML) or structure (DDL) of the database and want to ensure they either all occur successfully or none of them do (if one fails) then you would choose to use a transaction (TCL).

A transaction is also a good way to ensure an object is locked to prevent unexpected changes from occuring to it while you're making the changes that you intended.

> Or should I perform that operation using DML?

If you need to use a transaction, then you'll write TCL commands. Those TCL commands would surround the DML commands you write to modify the data. TCL and DML commands are not mutually exclusive, rather they're usually used in conjunction of each other.

An example of this (with SQL Server's T-SQL syntax) would look like:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION; -- TCL command to start a transaction 
    UPDATE dbo.Movies -- DML command to update the Movies table
    SET IsOldMovie = 1 -- Part of the DML query
    WHERE ReleaseYear < 2000; -- Part of the DML query
COMMIT; -- Closing TCL command to commit the change of the DML query above and end the transaction successfully
```

The different types of commands: DQL - Data Query Language, DDL - Data Definition Language, DML - Data Manipulation Language, DCL - Data Control Language, and TCL - Transaction Control Language, are all just categories of different commands of the same relational programming language, SQL. Please see [SQL | DDL, DQL, DML, DCL and TCL Commands](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-ddl-dql-dml-dcl-tcl-commands/) for more information on the differences.

---

> What if an error occurred during the insert of data and some data a partial inserted and what about ACID property am I getting any advantage from not using TCL commands?

Every query runs in an implicit transaction, making it consistent (the **C** in A**C**ID principles) within itself. This means for any **single** DML query, such as an `INSERT`, it is not possible for only some of the data to be changed (inserted). Either all of the data will be inserted or none of it will.

The benefit of not wrapping DML commands in TCL commands is improved concurrency and performance, since every database object wrapped in the same explicit transaction is locked for the entirety of the transaction. So if you had ten `UPDATE` statements, each for a different table, those ten tables would be locked from other queries for the entire duration of the explicit TCL transaction command. The tradeoff is if you didn't wrap all ten queries in the same explicit transaction (TCL command) then you risk an inconsistent state if only some of the `UPDATE`s worked successfully. Within an explicit transaction, if one of the ten `UPDATE`s failed, all ten would be undone (rolled back).

> Could you please give an example of the case required of using DML commands directly to insert data, isn't a risk?

It isn't a risk in the case where multiple DML commands are not dependent on each other. If you had three `UPDATE` queries that were unrelated to each other and didn't matter if one failed or not, then you wouldn't need to use a TCL command to wrap all three together.

Comment: As a side note: the need to write `begin transaction` also depends on the database and the SQL client used. In Oracle it's extremely unusual to use that, as you typically run with autocommit _disabled_

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Right, I made sure to specify that is T-SQL syntax, in my answer. Seems like OP tagged a few different RDMBS but was just asking about TCL in general.

Comment: @J.D. thanks for the clarification but I have to ask again, what if an error occurred during the insert of data and some data a partial inserted and what about ACID property am I getting any advantage from not using TCL commands, could you please give an example of the case required of using DML commands directly to insert data, isn't a risk?

Comment: @donaldjbrewer Please see the end of my updated answer which addresses your additional questions.

Comment: @J.D. God bless you, thank you for sharing the knowledge you cleared my doubts

Comment: @donaldjbrewer No problem! Glad to be of help!